# How to merge some rows of a CSV based on conditions?

Tags: python, excel, csv, merge

I have data in a CSV file, I need to merge some of the rows based on conditions. This Ex. for what I want, There are two conditions that must be met in order to merge the rows. To be of the same text and to be of the same type.

For example. B3,B4 have the same type (C3,C4) and in the same text(A3). So merge B3 and B4. All rows From A3 to A8 in the same text and from A4 to A8 empty rows. From A9 another text so, it's not empty.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help write a Python program to do this thing?

Comment: What module are you using to read the file? Please [edit] your question and add this information along with the code of your own attempt to do what you describe.

Comment: @martineau I tried by panda, but I'm new programmer, I don't know how to deal with it. But the pictures describe what I need. Thank you for your helping

Comment: Sorry, I'm no pandas expert. A viable alternative would be to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in Python's standard library — so I suggest you take a look at the documentation and try writing some code using it. If you can't figure out how to make the code work, _then_ ask a question and put your attempt in it. Note the tricky part will likely be grouping the rows you want to process together.

Comment: @martineau I have to check where the text starts and then see where is the next text and take the previous line, then apply the terms. Then continue to the last row. This is complicated for me as I am a new programmer

Comment: Then make that your question and show your attempt.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my very simple solution using the Pandas `groupby` function (to group by the `Type`) along with the `agg` function (for aggregation).
Documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

```py
df.groupby(by=['Text','Type']).agg('.'.join)
```

where `df` is your dataframe.

The only thing is it only works when you have the name of the person (i.e. John or Julia) in ALL of 'Text' rows of the dataframe.

Therefore my dataframe `df` looked as follows:

```
    Text    Product     Type
0   John    Earphone    Mobile accessories
1   John    Headsets    Mobile accessories
2   John    Mobile      Mobile
3   John    PlayStation Game
4   John    Xbox        Game
5   John    Perfume     beautiful smell
6   Julia   Makeup      Cosmetic
7   Julia   Perfume     beautiful smell
8   Julia   Foundation  Cosmetic
```

and here is the output

```
Text    Type                Product
John    Game                PlayStation.Xbox
        Mobile              Mobile
        Mobile accessories  Earphone.Headsets
        beautiful smell     Perfume
Julia   Cosmetic            Makeup.Foundation
        beautiful smell     Perfume
```

It shouldn't be too hard to fill the empty rows of the 'Text' column. Perhaps you could use NumPy's [full](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) function